# UML Use Case Diagram - can i re-use a use case

Tags: uml, use-case-diagram

[image]

So this is a snippet of my Use Case Diagram. I haven't done these in a while and have a few questions.

Quotation, Invoice, Address and Customer are all objects in my program.
When creating a quotation there is an option to add a customer or address associated with this quotation, (same case for Invoice). This process simply creates an association between the two objects. (In the application the user simply clicks on an "add customer button", then a window pops up and the user selects a customer from the available list of customers and clicks "Add")

I was wondering whether its possible to represent this without having to duplicate the "Add Customer" use case, every time I create an association between a customer and some object.

Update: I guess my question is not whether i should use extend or include but more whether I actually need the use cases "AddCustomer" and "AddAddress" or if they can just be included in "CreateQuotation".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [include or extend in UML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43461502/include-or-extend-in-uml)

Comment: As a side note: the arrows are the wrong side around. Or it should rather be `<<extend>>` than `<<include>>`.

Comment: Though the `<<include>>` is now in the correct direction, I recommend to read the linked answer. This also explains where you should/could use I/E.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same UseCase for both casses but, in detailed model, realization of for example AddCustomer in CreateQuotation may differ from realization in CreateInvoice. 
OR rename UseCases .. AddCustomerForQuotation and AddCustomerForInvoice ...