# which is the correct way to use in Use Case Diagram

Tags: uml, use-case, use-case-diagram

[image: Picture 1]

[image: Picture 2]

I just create this diagram  can anyone tell me if these 2 pictures are correct or wrong and which one should I use?,  can anyone tell  which is correct in these 2 pictures.

Answer (score 1):

Both diagrams are ok, except:

- the association between an actor and a use case should be straight lines and not directed arrows.  These arrows are an obsolete practice.
- the subject rectangle should be closed
- actors not related to anything are useless and should be removed

The question of whether `add` and `edit` should be in the same use case or in distinct ones is up to you to decide:

- grouping them has the benefit of simplifying the model.  `Manage students` could be even [more generic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37629197/3723423) and is quite common.
- keeping them separate may appear more granular but makes sense if there are different actors or if the business needs are very different.

You may read more to make up your mind, googling for `CRUD Use case`.