# How to create a use case diagram for these cases?

Tags: uml, crud, use-case-diagram

Let's say there are three actors, an Employee, an Employer, and an Administrator.

- We can create an account in this system - in this case, an `Employer`
  the role would be the default one.
- We can enter the system by `Log-in` to it.
- We can view a list of items without being authenticated.
- We can search for items without being authenticated.
- An employer can manage the items (add, delete, edit).
- An administrator can disable/enable an account, delete items, and add items.

The employee is an anonymous user basically and can view the list of items or search for them, same as an administrator or employer (authenticated users).

How should a UML use case diagram for these cases look like: I am unsure if there should be a use case i.e. add an item, delete an item, edit an item or "Manage items"?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: An draw.io but I am not sure how to list these use cases. Separately add, edit etc. Or add one use case, manage?

Comment: I see. This is more specific. Does this other answer help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65665579/which-is-the-correct-way-to-use-in-use-case-diagram/68666580#68666580 ?

Comment: Yes, that is the answer I was looking for.